# Specify complete path of view file in spring controller instead of using view resolver

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Is it possible to specify complete path of a view file in controller without making use of view resolver?

Suppose I have just one file, say a XML file in my views and for a particular request I want to serve that XML file. By using view resolver, I am not able to find a way to pick up such a file and server it directly like me serve a jsp. So, for such a case can I do something in which I specify complete path in controller like we used to do in servlet's `getRequestDispatcher`?

My view resolver is currently configured for JSP only, I am not able to find a view using view resolvers to handle this situation, my view resolver is like as given below:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix">
    <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
</property>
<property name="suffix">
    <value>.jsp</value>
</property>
```

Currently I am using `getRequestDispatcher` in controller for this? Is there any spring based alternative?

Comment: Return a `View` instead of a `String`. A `String` is (by default) interpreted as a viewname and passed to a `ViewResolver`, you can always return a `View` implementation pointing to your specific file.

Comment: @M.Deinum could you please elaborate it a little, I am not able to find any resource explaining use of `View`

Comment: See [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-return-types) for supported return types, and [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/View.html) for available `View` implementations. You probably want to return an `InternalResourceView` pointing to your resource.

Comment: You could also set up a different `InternalResourceViewResolver` with a restricted set of `viewNames` so that only this view resolves (and others are handled by the JSP one).

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks I got it working using `InternalResourceView` , you could have provided this solution in an answer instead of comment so I would be able to accept that to help others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring MVC allows you to create a request handling method with different return types, see the [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-return-types). Instead of a `String` return a `View` from your method which points directly to your resource. When you return a `View` instance Spring MVC will not consult a `ViewResolver` but simply use the view as is. For you case you probably want to use an [`InternalResourceView`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/InternalResourceView.html).

```
@RequestMapping
public View yourRequestHandlingMethod() {
    return new InternalResourceView("path/to/resource");   
}
```